# Linq - EntityFramework NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var caseList = (from x in context.Cases
         where allowedCaseIds.Contains(x => x.CaseId)
         select new Case {
            CaseId = x.CaseId,
            NotifierId = x.NotifierId,
            Notifier = x.NotifierId.HasValue ? new Notifier { Name = x.Notifier.Name } : null // This line throws exception
         }).ToList();
```

A `Case` class can have 0..1 `Notifier`

The query above will result in the following `System.NotSupportedException`:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'Models.Notifier'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported
>   in this context.

At the moment the only workaround I found is to loop the query result afterwards and manually populate `Notifier`like this:

```
foreach (var c in caseList.Where(x => x.NotifierId.HasValue)
{
    c.Notifier = (from x in context.Notifiers 
                 where x.CaseId == c.CaseId
                 select new Notifier {
                     Name = x.Name
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But I really don't want to do this because in my actual scenario it would generate hundreds of additional queries.

Is there any possible solution for a situation like this?.

Comment: What really are you trying to achieve with the projection? Isn't `Case` an entity and `x.Notifier` a navigation property? I mean, remove the whole custom `select` and use `context.Cases.Include(c => c.Notifier)`

Comment: I'm printing a list of Cases in which I need to display the Notifier name (among many other things). Yes, Notifier is a navigation property with 0..1 multiplicity

Comment: So again, why not just **including** it then?

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong. Case is part of my viewmodel

Comment: I see. And `Notifier` is not the same type as `x.Notifier`.

Comment: Have you tried to move the projection outside of the db, like `context.Cases.Where(...).AsEnumerable().Select(x => ...)`

Comment: Yes, I tried. But this is generating hundreds of queries again as I have lazy loading enabled. Note that the example I gave is a reduced one. Actually the model is much more complex

Comment: You need to include any navigation properties you are going to access after you switch to in memory. `context.Cases.Include(c => c.Notifier).Where(c => allowedCaseIds.Contains(x => x.CaseId).AsEnumerable().Select(x => ...)`. If there are a lot and that becomes inefficient you can load up related data as separate query before hand and the context will join it up when you access the navigation property.

Comment: FYI, tried entity model classed similar to yours, projecting to view model classes like in the example query, and **did not** get an exception.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to do that in two steps. First you can fetch only the data what you need with an anonymous type in a single query:

```
var caseList = (from x in context.Cases
     where allowedCaseIds.Contains(x => x.CaseId)
     select new {
        CaseId = x.CaseId,
        NotifierId = x.NotifierId,
        NotifierName = x.Notifier.Name
     }).ToList();
```

After that, you can work in memory:

```
List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
foreach (var c in caseList)
{
    var case = new Case();
    case.CaseId = c.CaseId;
    case.NotifierId = c.NotifierId;
    case.NotifierName = c.NotifierId.HasValue ? c.NotifierName : null;
    cases.Add(case);
}
```

Comment: This works indeed. But the only problem for me is that actually the Case entity is much more complex than the one I presented here and mapping the anonymous type would really bloat the code making really hard to maintain later.

Comment: I thought the main problem here is to prevent the loop :-) Well, if your entities are more complex, then it depends on the scenario and how complex they really are and the logic in your linq query. Sometimes it is better to have a single query, but sometimes it can be faster to have multiple queries (of course not in the loop... but to load some of the lookup data, which you can reuse in your mapping). If you put too much logic in the query, It can become very hard to mantain and test. In this case I find it more important to prevent the complexity, than having some additional lines of code.

Comment: You are right, he he, I didn't specify that. I'm currently "bloating" the code so I can perform a couple of tests and decide which strategy to choose. The query loop is indeed what I need to avoid. Either way if no other solutions are proposed I will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing your query as a chain of function calls rather than a query expression, then put an `.AsEnumerable()` in between:

```
var caseList = context.Clases
    .Where(x => allowedCaseIds.Contains(x.CaseId))
    .AsEnumerable()                                 // Switch context
    .Select(x => new Case() {
        CaseId = x.CaseId,
        NotifierId = x.NotifierId,
        Notifier = x.NotifierId.HasValue
            ? new Notifier() { Name = x.Notifier.Name }
            : null
    })
    .ToList();
```

This will cause EF to generate an SQL query only up to the point where you put the `.AsEnumerable()`, further down the road, LINQ to Objects will do all the work. This has the advantage that you can use code that cannot be translated to SQL and should not require a lot of changes to your existing code base (unless you're using a lot of `let` expressions...)

Comment: If you have lazy loading disabled, you need to add .Include(x => x.Modifier) otherwise x.Notifier.Name will not work. But this will fetch all other properties of Modifier as well, even if you don't need them. If you have lazy loading enabled, you will have additional queries again.